# Как выйти за ширину родительского блока при абсолютном позиционировании и растянуть этот блок до границ краёв окна браузера

Tags: html, css

Как вылезти за ширину родительского блока при абсолютном позиционировании?
Нужно чтобы у псевдоэлемента (его бекграунд) растянулся за пределы `.container`.

```css
.container {
  width: 960px
}
.element {
  position: relative;
}
.element:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(picture.png);
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А можете сделать ваш код запускаемым и пояснить в чём проблема сделать абсолютно позиционируемый элемент просто больше контейнера (к примеру, за счёт свойства `width`)?

Answer (score 1):

Если растянуть нужно не на какой-то контейнер, а на окно браузера, то можно применить `vw`:

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

section:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((100% - 100vw) / 2);
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Comment: то что нужно,а что для ие с 10 версий делать? я насчёт vw

Comment: @J.Doe, использовать вариант с лишним контейнером из соседнего ответа :)

Comment: он не подошёл,увы(

Comment: @J.Doe, хотя стоп. [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) говорит, что IE10 поддерживает `vw`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>В общем случае никак.</s> Был неправ, в некоторых случаях можно.

Можно легко вылазить только на фиксированное расстояние, но растянуть до краёв окна браузера не получится.

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

section:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Чтобы растянуть до краёв, можно использовать дополнительный контейнер:

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  height: 100px;
  /* no position */
  margin: auto;
}

section:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -50px; /* same as height */
  height: 50px;
  background: silver;
  opacity: 50%;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Если высота динамическая, то в примере выше можно (с осторожностью) вместо `margin-top` использовать transform translate. С осторожностью - из-за того, что место на блок будет оставаться снизу и в случае с концом позиционированного контейнера будет приводит к пустоте внизу.

Answer (score 0):

Да все работает, пример ниже.

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

.element:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100vw;
 transform: translateX(calc(-50vw + 200px));
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Поправил код. Ширина - 100vw, потом transform с вычислением. В сниппете здесь и на [сайте тестовом](http://test.test/so/621153.html) все ОК.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы автер растягивался на все 100%

Comment: Можно и так, поправил ответ. Растягивается на ширину окна браузера.